# Improve performance on updating stock for 4000 variants in SHOPIFY

Tags: python, rest, shopify, shopify-api

I've made an app for shopify REST-API coded in python to update stock for 4000 variants from 750 different products that I get from a local machine mySQL database.

I have an intermidiate table where I get all the product information then I sync their variants, stock and price. As far as I've read, you can only update shopify variant's stock (inventory available) one by one. [Info here](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2021-10/resources/inventorylevel#%5Bpost%5D/admin/api/2021-10/inventory_levels/set.json)

@Abhishek told me to use Threading. Could anyone give me some guides how to use this?

This is my previous explanation of my problem:

*Everything runs smothly except when it runs the "for each" cicle to POST the available stock from "myList" (previously appended).
requests.post(send_url, myList[index])
It lasts about 65minutes.
Is there any way to bulk it, in one operation or optimize it to a faster way?*

Thanks.

Comment: https://creativedata.stream/multi-threading-api-requests-in-python/

Comment: there are limit when using the shopify api  https://shopify.dev/api/usage/rate-limits

Answer (score 2):

Shopify has Bulk Inventory Updates. Just as quick pointer. You can update 100 SKUs with one API call. So 4000 variants is only 40 calls. That is not going to be a problem. I update 40,000 SKUs without writing any exotic code.

If you do a bulk update, it is even easier. You upload a single JSON file with your updates, and Shopify does all the work.

You have plenty of options and none of them involve Multi-threading API Requests.

Comment: Hi David,
could you please tell me where you find this info?
Inside their docu, there was no such option... at least I couldn't find it

Comment: And what do you think about what Andrew Ryan answers above?
Thanks

Comment: https://shopify.dev/api/admin-graphql/2022-01/objects/BulkOperation#top

And no, you are not having problems due to rate limits when you examine this from the bulk perspective. If you choose to ignore doing this in bulk, then yes, trick out your calls to respect limits.

Comment: Oh! you are refering to GraphQL info. 
I used REST-API... I'm really noob at coding and din't figure it out using GraphQL, yet.
Do you think there is a way for REST-API?

Comment: I doubt there is an easy way to do this with RestAPI. You are left with rate limited calls one variant at a time, since you now have use InventoryLevel endpoint.

Comment: Thank you very much.
Great appreciation.

Comment: Hi again @David Lazar ,
could you please show us an example how you do this bulk update to your variants?

Comment: What aspect of that is troubling you? I do not feel comfortable pasting hundreds of lines of code here as that will just confuse you more.

Comment: My main concern is that I could find the way to update the price for 2 products with its variants at the same time.
I've just developed this part of code, and playing around with postman I could achieve my goal.
With only 1 product and its variants, there is no problem.
Then, it means if I have 700 products = 700 GQL query's.
That's only for prices, then stock cycle, another hundreds more.

Comment: It is per SKU. You would never make 700 API calls unless you had 70,000 SKUs. 

And yes, changing prices is not the same. That is because while inventory can have a single SKU stored a N locations, a single SKU has a single price at all those locations, so the update pattern is indeed different.

Comment: I don't know where we differed in this conversation. I'll try to clarify.
As I tryed to mention before for prices, 700 product_id, as far as I could achieve updating, were 700 query calls. Each product_id has many variants (SKU), those can be updated at once.

In the other hand, for stocks, now (I think I saw it before), I can't find a bulky way to update them without calculation "delta". Isn't it?
I'd like to write available stock directly. As I'm doing in REST API, but in a bulky way and faster.

Comment: @DavidLazar A quick follow up question: I assume you're talking about the the inventoryBulkAdjustQuantityAtLocation mutation Shopify offers (https://shopify.dev/api/admin-graphql/2022-04/mutations/inventoryBulkAdjustQuantityAtLocation) - the problem with that mutation is that it only seems to allow incremental adjustments of the stock levels. If I wanted to set absolute stock levels Shopify's API doesn't seem to offer any bulk operations or am I missing something?

Comment: Here is the deal. If you download your inventory in bulk, you have stock right now. Set a key:value per SKU and quantity. Now, since you want an absolute level, when you write your new key:value for that, use the value you desire and the current amount to calculate your delta change to arrive at that level. SIMPLE MATH. Now you have your bulk SKU:quantity levels to set. Tada. Magic.

Comment: Hello @DavidLazar. Do you have any experience that could provide us an estimate of how long it might take to update 100,000 variants using the bulk API endpoint?

Comment: I cannot give you a number for that as it is internal to Shopify. It will not be 10 minutes I can tell you that. I would also spend the extra time to ask for the result to be sent to you as a Webhook so you don't Poll.